# change the summary statistics in gtsummary table

Tags: r, gtsummary

I've created a summary table with gtsummary. But I want to make some changes to the summary statistics. I would like the % to be a percentage of the total sum for each level, and not the entire variable.
For grade 1 the total sum would be 68. So for drug A I want it to say 35(51.47%) (35/68x100). Similarly for drug B it would show 33(48.53%).
How would I do that? Thanks a lot!

```
library(gtsummary)
data(trial)
trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, grade)
trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `percent = "row"` to your `tbl_summary` call

```r
trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    percent = 'row')
```

[image]